# Create gradle task based on product flavor dimensions

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

I had the following productFlavors in my build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {

    free {

    }
    paid {

    }       
}
```

Now I added a flavorDimension (http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-flavor-variants) like this:

```
flavorDimensions "payment", "releasetype"

productFlavors {

    paid {
        dimension "payment"
    }
    free {
        dimension "payment"
    }
    beta {
        dimension "releasetype"
    }

    major {
        dimension "releasetype"
    }
}
```

I am using [this script](https://github.com/mgouline/android-samples/blob/master/jacoco/jacoco.gradle) to generate gradle tasks for jacoco coverage reports. 
That script combines the build types (debug, release) with the product flavors (paid, free, ...) and generates tasks accordingly.

This is, of course, broken with the flavor dimensions, because the script does not take them into account.

The script generates the tasks:

```
testDebugPaidUnitTestCoverage
testDebugFreeUnitTestCoverage
testDebugBetaUnitTestCoverage
testDebugMajorUnitTestCoverage
```

What it should do is:

```
testDebugPaidBetaUnitTestCoverage
testDebugPaidMajorUnitTestCoverage
...
```

I tried accessing the flavorDimensions in the gradle task via

```
android.flavorDimensions
```

but it doesn't recognize the property:

```
Error:Could not get unknown property 'flavorDimensions' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.
```

Any suggestions on how I could expand this script to work with flavor dimensions or how to access them from my external jacoco.gradle script?

I can access the build types and product flavors from there, so this shoulld be possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think Sam was on the right path with [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66693162/315702), but didn't explain why variants are the key, nor did he tie his examples to the associated script. I'll take a crack at answering this.

The problem is that the script loops over product flavors and then, in a nested loop, build types:

```
productFlavors.each { productFlavorName ->
    buildTypes.each { buildTypeName ->
        ...
    }
}
```

Since `productFlavors` is a list of all instances of `ProductFlavor`, and not a list of all *combinations* of `ProductFlavor` across dimensions, this doesn't provide the multi-dimensional support you're looking for.

Variants give you the all the combinations of product flavors and build types. Instead of the nested loops, simply loop over applicationVariants or libraryVariants, depending on whether you're working with an application or a library. For example:

```
applicationVariants.each { variantName ->
    ...
}
```

Looking at the script, I see that you'll run into a challenge: the script constructs a source-directory path in such a way that the buildType-directory is a child of the product-flavor directory: `sourcePath = "${productFlavorName}/${buildTypeName}"`. Since the variant name is all one string, this kind of path construction wouldn't work. However, many years have passed since this question was asked, and the rest of the script would probably need to be overhauled anyway.

Another collection Gradle gives you that could be handy is `flavorDimensions`. In the case of the example, these would be the strings "payment" and "releasetype". With some fancy looping, it would be possible to reproduce the combinations that you get "for free" with variants.

Answer (score 0):

I am not good with gradle.

But maybe you can try the following

if your module is library;

```
variants = android.libraryVariants.collect { var ->
    var.name
}
```

if your module is application;

```
variants = android.applicationVariants.collect { var ->
    var.name
}
```